# making List<string> compatible for datagridview column?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datagridview

My data gridview is not bound to a datasource and it has a combo box name `Test2`. I am inserting string in it run time.Following is my code

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test2"];
      string[] arr1 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
      comboBox.Items.AddRange(arr1);
```

But rather array of strings i am interested in using `List<string>`.For that code i wrote is this

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Test2"];
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("a");
        data.Add("b");
        data.Add("c");
        comboBox.Items.AddRange(data);
```

But now `datagridview combo box` is showing `(Collection)` string only. Any idea how can i make `List<string>` working.Workaround is this I can do is change `List<string>` to array of strings but it will be inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DataSource and DataBind()?

Comment: @Peter this data is coming from a `distinct` query and i think so when you bind the `datasource` you will get all the data instead of a particular query.

Comment: @Peter you are Right about the `DataSource` part, sorry no `DataBind()` for winform

Comment: than do accept answer if it works for you

Comment: Ah yes, I come from an ASP.NET background :) But I think using DataSource will still be a better solution. Accept Pranay Rana's answer with the green checkmark if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Peter please can you give me some good tutorials Links of `DataSource` that you are talking about Thanks.

Comment: Well, I meant the solution provided by Pranay Rana (which uses DataSource). I'm no WinForms expert but if you Google around for 'Winforms DataSource tutorial' for example, you'll definitely find lots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but can you do something like this

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn d = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); 
List<string> data = new List<string>();        
data.Add("a");         
data.Add("b");         
data.Add("c"); 
d.DataSource = data ;
```